# Compiling .f file, "undefined reference to 'MAIN_' issue

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile an .f file using [g77](http://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/g77.html).
I tried to compile it with .cmd batch file (as per one of the ways described in g77 [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/g77/)) with the following content (in .cmd file):

```
g77 -o gtemp.exe gtemp.f
pause
```

But when I run the upper .cmd file, I get the following error message:
"undefined reference to 'MAIN_'

Why is this happening? The gtemp.f file is in the same folder as g77.exe file. Thank you.

Here is the code for the gtemp.f file:

```
      SUBROUTINE GTEMP(DIF,TMIN,TMAX,TAV,TG)                                    GTEMP    2
      DIMENSION AMON(12),TG(12)                                                 GTEMP    3
      DATA AMON / 15.,46.,74.,95.,135.,166.,196.,227.,258.,288.,                GTEMP    4
     1            319.,349. /                                                   GTEMP    5
      DATA P,PI,PO / 8760.,3.14159265,0.6 /                                     GTEMP    6
C                                                                               GTEMP    7
      BETA   = SQRT(PI/(DIF*P))*10.                                             GTEMP    8
      X      = EXP(-BETA)                                                       GTEMP    9
      X2     = X*X                                                              GTEMP   10
      C      = COS(BETA)                                                        GTEMP   11
      S      = SIN(BETA)                                                        GTEMP   12
      Y      = X2 - 2.*X*C + 1.                                                 GTEMP   13
      Y      = Y / (2.*BETA*BETA)                                               GTEMP   14
      GM     = SQRT(Y)                                                          GTEMP   15
      Z      = (1.-X*(C+S)) / (1.-X*(C-S))                                      GTEMP   16
      PHI    = ATAN(Z)                                                          GTEMP   17
      BO     = (TMAX-TMIN)*0.5                                                  GTEMP   18
      DO 40 I=1,12                                                              GTEMP   19
      THETA  = AMON(I)*24.                                                      GTEMP   20
   40 TG(I)  = TAV - BO*COS(2.*(PI/P)*THETA-PO-PHI)*GM + 460.                   GTEMP   21
      RETURN                                                                    GTEMP   22
      END                                                                       GTEMP   23
```

Comment: Your code is a subroutine, not a program. It cannot be run alone, you need a main program that calls the subroutine. If you want to compile it separately and link it with the program later, use the `-c` argument to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I changed the upper "-o" in .cmd file to "-c". Now I am getting a message: "gtemp.exe  There's no such a file or directory".
Is there any way I could run this subroutine as a separate script?

Comment: No, it is a subroutine. You MUST have a main program which calls it. You cannot produce an exe from it and you cannot run it separately.

Comment: I can not get that .exe file.
Nevertheless, thank you for your time and helpful replies.

Comment: Who calls `gtemp` and gives it values of `dif` `tmin` `tmax` `tav` and `tg`?

Comment: I do not know Ross. I found this file, and thought I could I could execute it. I did not know it was this subroutine thing.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when the compiler cannot find a main program.

Create a main program  as follows

```
Program Test
Implicit None 

Real :: DIF, TMIN, TMAX, TAV, TG(12) 

Call GTEMP(DIF,TMIN,TMAX,TAV,TG)

Contains

  SUBROUTINE GTEMP(DIF,TMIN,TMAX,TAV,TG)
  ..... 
  END SUBROUTINE GTEMP

End Program Test
```

Comment: Thank you Zeus.
Do I need to save your code as Test.f?

Comment: You can save it using any name you want

Comment: Thank you Zeus. I still do understand what I need to do. Do I need to compile (make Test.exe from Test.f file first)? Then run the upper .cmd file?

Comment: Yes, you have to compile and link.

Comment: I tried making a new .cmf file with the following content:
```g77 -c Test.exe Test.f
pause```

But when I run it, I get a message: "Test.exe: No such file or directory".

Comment: g77 -c Test.f -o Test.exe

Comment: Thank you.
I am getting two invalid first character messages for Test.f:

```Invalid first character at (^) [info -f g77 M LEX]
Test.f:2:
    Implicit None```
and:
```Invalid first character at (^) [info -f g77 M LEX]
Test.f:4:
    Real :: DIF, TMIN, TMAX, TAV, TG (12)```
And non-numeric error messages:
```Non-numeric character at (^) in label field [info -f g77 M LEX]
Test.f: 11:
     -----```