# makefile:35: recipe for target 'LBM' failed

Tags: makefile, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

This question is a sequel to an earlier question posted in Stackoverflow in the following link: [Array specification at (1) has more than 7 dimensions in mpif-sizeof.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114824/array-specification-at-1-has-more-than-7-dimensions-in-mpif-sizeof-h/65121778#65121778)

In the earlier problem the compilation worked till the end but while preparing the MF_LBM.cpu file, some errors were output as follows:

```
mpifort -c  -ofast -p -ffree-line-length-300  Monitor_special_case.F90
mpifort  -ofast -p -ffree-line-length-300  -o MF_LBM.cpu Main_multiphase.o Main_singlephase.o Module.o Init_multiphase.o Init_singlephase.o Misc.o IO_multiphase.o IO_singlephase.o Kernel_multiphase.o Kernel_singlephase.o Mpi_misc.o Mpi_pdf.o Mpi_pdf_acc.o Boundary_singlephase.o Boundary_singlephase_special_case.o Boundary_multiphase_inlet.o Boundary_multiphase_outlet.o Boundary_multiphase_other.o Boundary_multiphase_special_case.o Monitor.o Phase_gradient.o Monitor_special_case.o
/usr/bin/ld: Main_multiphase.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: Init_multiphase.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: Misc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: IO_multiphase.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: Mpi_misc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: Mpi_pdf.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against undefined symbol `_mpi_variable_0_' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: Monitor.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against undefined symbol `_mpi_variable_0_' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/gcrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:35: recipe for target 'LBM' failed
make: *** [LBM] Error 1
```

I am using the following versions of items:

1. gfortran 7.5.0
2. open mpi 2.1.1
3. make 4.1

Comment: We have quite a few questions about what `undefined reference to 'main'` means. Did you read them? Do you have an actual main program among the files you are compiling?

Comment: No, I don't have any file named 'main'. You can see that in the makefile that I have attached at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114824/array-specification-at-1-has-more-than-7-dimensions-in-mpif-sizeof-h/65121778#65121778

Comment: Not a file.  You need to define a _function_ named `main`.  That's the function the operating system will call when it starts your program.  Without that the system doesn't know what to do first when your program starts.  This has nothing to do with make: the title of your question is misleading.  That error is just make telling you "hey, some command I ran didn't work".  You have to fix the reason the command (in this case the linker) failed.  The title of the question should be "undefined reference to `main'" or something.

Comment: However I don't know if there's something special that needs to happen with all these different parts.  In any event, the problem is not make per se (although you may have to modify the options etc. in your makefile to get it working, not sure)

Comment: The main function in Fortran is the one declared with `program foo .... end program foo`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753150/undefined-reference-to-main-when-compiling-a-module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948943/compiling-f-file-undefined-reference-to-main-issue